# Reading gif file from base64 into picturebox any other way? C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I Have gif image in base64.

Currently I am approaching this way. reading base64 gif file and writing it to byte array and writing it back to image file to disk and reading from the file to picturebox.image.

```
 byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(body);
                //*  this is write file to disk and read
                string filename = Username;
                File.WriteAllBytes(filename, imageBytes);
                fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
```

Now, I want to write it to memory without writing it to disk file. like in a form of variable image. that can be assigned to picturebox. Is there any possible of this. because I have to do repeatedly many times for many images.

So I would like find a different approach without writing saving file to disk and reading it again.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(body);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(body);
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Be aware the `MemoryStream` class is IDisposable so you should `Dispose()` it. This can happen with using or with try/catch/finally block.

Comment: `MemoryStream` is `IDisposable` only because it inherits from the abstract class `Stream`, which Microsoft was silly enough to make `IDisposable`, thus forcing all classes in the hierarchy to also be `IDisposable`.  However, `MemoryStream` will behave just fine if you never dispose it.

Comment: @MikeNakis okay after little research I can agree, calling Dispose in this case won't clean up the memory used by MemoryStream any faster. But it is a good practice to always Dispose your IDisposable classes. Also in future implementation is possible to be added resources which need to be dispose. so this will not harm if he doesn't need to read/write from the stream anymore, but can help him avoid big troubles in the future.

Comment: Mike Nakis Thank you for your comment. By habit I added stream.close() and I got gdi error. I come back and read your comment. I removed stream.close() It works fine without error. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mybirthname you are right, doing things properly is preferable to taking shortcuts based on apocryphal knowledge of the implementation's inner workings.

Comment: @NewBie I am not sure why it would fail if you closed the stream but succeed if you did not close it.  Perhaps you did something else wrong.  All I said here is that it should not harm to forget to dispose a memory stream.  But it certainly should not hurt.